# Removing trailing zeroes without extra commands

Tags: java, printf

How can I get rid of trailing zeroes in a double without using decimal formatter, or any other extra command? Why do extra zeroes happen? I'm trying to make a table as an assignment, but I can't have extra zeroes behind the numbers. No extra commands are allowed.

```
public class CelctoFaren {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        double celsius = -40;
        double farenheit;
        double counter = celsius;

        while (counter < 0) {
            farenheit = 1.8 * celsius + 32;
            System.out.printf ("%fC\tis\t%fF\n", celsius, farenheit);
            celsius += 1;
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `printf` [format string specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) and you should find what you need. For example, instead of `%f`, you could use `%0.2f` and restrict the double values to two decimal places.

The reason you get all the trailing zeroes now is that `%f` does not restrict how many decimal places are printed and a `double` value has many.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String.format` example:

```
 System.out.println(String.format("%0.2f %0.2f", celsius, farenheit));
```